# How to create named lock in java?

Tags: java

**We can achive it in c# as follows-**

```
void readFile(File file)
{
      Mutex mutexForFile = null;                    
      bool mutexCreateFlag; // Return true/false based on whether mutext is already exist or it is created as part of current call
      mutexForFile = new Mutex(false, file.FullName.GetHashCode().ToString(), out mutexCreateFlag);                    
      if (!mutexCreateFlag)
          throw new Exception("File UsedByOtherProcess");
       else
       {
           mutexForFile .WaitOne();
           // synchronized access to resource
           ProcessFile(fileInfo: file);
           mutexForFile .ReleaseMutex();                    
       }
 }
```

Don't think about relevance of the code, just for example i have given

will somthing like this be possible in Java?

Comment: Uhm, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html

Comment: There is `Lock` class that will support this kind of functionality

Comment: Dear jeremy can u give me an example ( I am new to java).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you create a lock on an object.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html

Java also has the `synchronized` keyword as part of its language.  You might wanna start there, actually.

Comment: Unfortunately, have to downvote. The author of the question asked about named mutex objects of .NET framework. Named mutexes (and other named synchronization objects as well), unlike regular synchronization objects can be used for cross-process synchronization - and this expected use case is clear from the code example in the question. This answer cannot be used for cross-process synchronization

Answer (score 0):

Read this entire page :[Java Lock Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)